# Proof that $\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}} (1-\alpha j^2)\exp(-\frac{\alpha j^2}{2})$ is positive

Tags: analysis, inequality, summation

Pretty much as stated in the title, is the sum:
$\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}} (1-\alpha j^2)\exp(-\frac{\alpha j^2}{2})$ positive for $\alpha>0$?

The sum arose from a summation of gaussian kernels. I can compute the limits for $\alpha\to 0$ or $\alpha\to\infty$, which are $0$ and $1$ respectively. I've checked it numerically as well, so it is positive.

I've tried to derive it, but the derivative is even more intimidating, so I abandoned that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply [Poisson's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}f(n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\hat{f}(n)$ where $\hat{f}(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2i\pi xy}\,dx$: $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(1-\alpha n^2)e^{-\alpha n^2/2}=\frac{(2\pi)^{5/2}}{\alpha^{3/2}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}n^2 e^{-2(n\pi)^2/\alpha}\qquad(\alpha>0)$$ (omitting the computation of the Fourier transform). Now the answer is obvious.

Comment: Could you augment your answer by explaining which function $f$ you chose.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. If you're willing I would like to acknowledge your contribution in my publication in the acknowledgement section. If so, please contact me via j.w.spaak@gmail.com